# How to inject 2 instances of the same class to another 2 different classes using Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, ejb, inversion-of-control

My question is the following: Assume that you have a class Person which has 2 instances Adam and Jacobs. So, you have 2 another classes called School and University. My task is to define by injecting that Jacobs is studying in the school and Adam is an university student as well.

How to do it using Spring Framework? 
Code written answer is welcome :))

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: How about you show what you've done so far? This is not a homework service.

Comment: @BasdeGroot I am sorry, but I haven't any source code. The reason is that I've faced this kind of question in one of my Job interviews and still can't find a properly answer.

Comment: But that should not prevent you to try to make the source code for the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is to inject different instances of the same type in different components. You can do that by using spring @Qualifiers. I sketch a solution to the problem you shared.

Having the Person class.

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And a configuration for each person.

```
@Configuration
public class DemoConfig {

    @Bean
    public Person adam() {
        return new Person("Adam");
    }

    @Bean
    public Person jacobs() {
        return new Person("Jacobs");
    }
}
```

The School class.

```
@Component
public class School {

    private Person jacobs;

    public School(@Qualifier("jacobs") Person jacobs) {
        this.jacobs = jacobs;
    }

    public String personName() {
        return jacobs.getName();
    }
}
```

The university class is similar to the School class but changing the qualifier name to "adam".

Here is a test to your requirements.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private School school;

    @Autowired
    private University university;

    @Test
    public void testPersonDependencies() {
        assertThat(school.personName()).isEqualTo("Jacobs");
        assertThat(university.personName()).isEqualTo("Adam");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think technique you've applied is quite clear. You didn't annotate Person class by `@Component` because its instance name by default will be "person" in the container, so, then you wouldn't apply `@Qualifier` annotation. In order to avoid it, you have created two beans manually in the configuration and thus you can guarantee that two instances of the same class will have 2 different names given in configuration.  

Did I get it right?

Comment: You are right, I like that solution better for this example, in order to avoid the @Qualifier annotation